# Odd behaviour replacing "\"

Tags: c#

I have this issue in which I have a strnig with among other things the literal expression `"\\"` on several occasions and I want to replace it with `"\"`, when I try to replace it with string.replace, only replcaes the first occurrence, and if I do it with regular expression it doesn't replace it at all

I checked with some RegEx Testers online and supposedly my code is ok, returns what I meant to, but my code doesn't work at all

With `string.replace`

```
example = "\\\\url.com\\place\\anotherplace\\extraplace\\";

example = example.replace("\\\\","\\");

returns example == "\\url.com\\place\\anotherplace\\extraplace\\";
```

With RegEx

```
example = Regex.Replace(example,"\\\\","\\");

returns example = "\\\\url.com\\place\\anotherplace\\extraplace\\";
```

It is the same case if I use literals (On the Replace function parameters use `(@"\\", @"\")` gives the same result as above).

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I think my ultimate goal was confusing so I'll update it here, what I want to do is:

*Input:*
variable that holds the string: `"\\\\url.com\\place\\anotherplace\\extraplace\\"`

*Process*

*Output*
variable that holds the string `"\\url.com\place\anotherplace\extraplace\"`
(so I can send it to ffmpeg and it recognizes it as a valid route)

Comment: So, what the expected result you want?

Comment: What happens if you make the example variable a literal? (do example = @"\\\\url.com\\place\\anotherplace\\extraplace\\")

Comment: @JakeP The example in the app comes from some other variable, can I explicitly make it literal?. DaveZynch that works as expected, but I cant get it to work on every occurrence

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change this:

```
example = "\\\\url.com\\place\\anotherplace\\extraplace\\";
```

to this

```
example = @"\\\\url.com\\place\\anotherplace\\extraplace\\";
```

It wasn't the `Regex.Replace` parameters that was the problem.

Comment: The example comes from another variable, how can I make it literal ?(googling now)

Comment: if you're are passed `\\\\url.com\\place\\anotherplace\\extraplace\\` that really is (if you PRINT it on the screen or console this: '\\url.com\place\anotherplace\extraplace\'

Comment: "\" is an escape character. In string literals, "\\" resolves to just "\". The @ sign (which makes it a _verbatim_ string literal) makes it ignore escape characters, so @"\\" resolves to "\\", without verbatim, the string literal should be "\\\\" to get "\\".

Comment: Ok, I got it, it was a confusion with the different concepts. Thanks

Comment: @HansPassant: I rolled it back because he is being passed a url string that appears to already have been quoted. And he intends on making it a valid path.  At least I think that's the case here. In other words, the intent is to 'unquote' a the string.

Comment: Bad idea, it was the edited version that got all the votes.  Well, it's your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You only have one occurrence of `\\\\` in your string. So it is doing exactly what you asked it to do.

Without escaping (ie without adding extra /'s)

- What is your actual input?
- What is your desired output?

Comment: He actually has zero occurrences of literal \\\\ in his string and one occurrence of literal \\ because "\\\\" escapes out to \\, I think he really just wants to use the @ operator.

Comment: I think I'm a bit confusd, but I've updated the question if it's of any help

Comment: Ok, I got it, it was a confusion with the different concepts.

Answer (score 1):

You should change it to following

```
example = example.replace(@"\\", @"\");
```

Answer (score 1):

That appears to be the expected behavior.

In the String.Replace case:
Initially, example contains a string that starts with two backslashes, and contains a few single backslashes elsewhere in the string. You then attempted to replace all occurrences of double backslashes with a single backslash, which worked and produced a string that starts with a single backslash and contains a few single backslashes elsewhere in the string.

In the Regex.Replace case:
The original contents of example are irrelevant in this case. Your regex pattern is a double backslash, which when interpreted as a regex pattern, means "find a single backslash". You then replace this pattern with a single backslash, which results in no change to the string.